# Trying to convert GPS LatLng Android coordinates to use in ArcGIS rest - esriMeters

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, latitude-longitude, arcgis-rest-api

I am getting the LAT and LNG position from Android.
Both values are of type double, in Degrees.

For example: NY, USA
Latitude: 40.7142700
Longitude: -74.0059700

Then I have a service ArcGIS REST.
It uses esriMeters.

How do I convert Lat Lng to esriMeters and back?

---

More information:

Spatial Reference: 32721  (32721)

Comment: If it's esriMeters, then there's likely a spatial reference as well (aka coordinate system). What is it? Could be EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator).

Comment: It says: Spatial Reference: 32721 (32721).

Comment: Ah. Well, 32721 is WGS84 UTM 21 South. That's...odd. I think someone confused the latitude band designation, which is "S" for latitudes between 32 North and 40 North. Technically, your sample point is in band "T". However, the longitude value should be in zone 18 North, not 21 (North or South).

Comment: You are correct, the example I gave is wrong since it's outside the area.    Anyway, I want to convert LatLng to 32721(WGS84 UTM 21 South) and back.  Do you know how to convert it or where to get that information?   thanks.

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geometry/ProjectionTransformation.html ? (I don't know the various web APIs that well)

Answer (score 1):

This is simple technique you should use `com.esri.core.geometry.Point` class for converting your GPS lat and lng into ArcGIS map point. For Example:

```
private Point ConvertMyLocationPoint(final double x, final double y) {
        Point wgspoint = new Point(x, y);
        Point mapPoint = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(wgspoint, SpatialReference.create(4326),
                mMapView.getSpatialReference());

        return mapPoint;    
    }
```

Reference from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27921994/2311051)